S3 Logs not getting populated in case of timeout build in CodeBuild
I am seeing a very weird behaviour, where my codebuild is not populating logs when it is experiencing timeout in any of its phases. It correctly populates S3 logs in case of success or failure scenario in the right bucket but in case of timeout, it simply doesn't provide anything.
Can someone help with this?
Setup:-
1. I am using Java's AWS-SDK to create a code-build project from my code
.environment(ProjectEnvironment.builder()
                        .type(EnvironmentType.LINUX_CONTAINER)
                        .image("aws/codebuild/standard:7.0")
                        .computeType(ComputeType.BUILD_GENERAL1_LARGE)
                        .imagePullCredentialsType(ImagePullCredentialsType.CODEBUILD)
                        .build())
                .timeoutInMinutes(5)
                .queuedTimeoutInMinutes(480)
                .logsConfig(logsConfig)
                .build();

Logs Config
S3LogsConfig s3LogsConfig = S3LogsConfig.builder()
        .bucketOwnerAccess(BucketOwnerAccess.FULL)
        .encryptionDisabled(false)
        .location("<Loc>")
        .status("ENABLED")
        .build();

CloudWatchLogsConfig cloudWatchLogsConfig = CloudWatchLogsConfig.builder()
        .status("DISABLED")
        .build();

LogsConfig logsConfig = LogsConfig.builder()
        .cloudWatchLogs(cloudWatchLogsConfig)
        .s3Logs(s3LogsConfig)
        .build();

Is there something which I am missing here in the configuration ?
I tried increasing the timeout for my build but that is also not helping. In a happy scenario I am looking that in case of timeouts also, I should be provided logs back in my S3 bucket.

you can use a lambda to check your build status, you can populate your s3 logs from the lambda code, so if it timeouts it will give you log, however this may only work if your codebuild project completes within 15 mins as you might know lambda has a timeout of 15 mins
